# Mysql query to update record based on other row in same table (with inputparameter)

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I have this table to store articles from different suppliers. These are the most important table fields of my table "artPerBrand":

```
|ID     | ArtNrShort   | ArtNrLong   | SupplierID 
--------------------------------------------------
|45     | mik25        | mike25_002  | 1
|326    | mik25        |             | 2
```

I check the table for rows (with the same ArtNrShort) if I find one I want to update the one with the empty ArtNrLong with the value of the exististing ArtNrLong. I do need the input parameter "varArtNrShort" as I need to take care of some different scenarios in the future.

I am not a SQL guru but I came up with this query which should be almost there. However when I execute this (Python) ArtNrLong of ID 326 stays empty. What am I missing here?

```
varArtNrShort = 'mik25'
sql = "UPDATE artPerBrand t1 JOIN artPerBrand t2 ON t1.ArtNrShort = t2.ArtNrShort SET t1.ArtNrLong = t2.ArtNrLong WHERE t1.ArtNrLong = '' AND t2.ArtNrLong <> '' AND t1.ArtNrShort = '%s'"
val = (varArtNrShort)
cur.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
```

I changed my query to this:

```
"UPDATE artPerBrand a1 INNER JOIN artPerBrand a2 ON a1.ArtNrShort = a2.ArtNrShort SET a1.ArtNrLong = a2.ArtNrLong WHERE a2.ArtNrLong IS NOT NULL AND a1.ArtNrLong IS NULL AND a1.ArtNrShort = 'mik25'"
```

Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. ArtNrLong is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following self join approach here:

```sql
UPDATE artPerBrand a1
INNER JOIN artPerBrand a2
    ON a2.ArtNrShort = a1.ArtNrShort
SET a1.ArtNrLong = a2.ArtNrLong
WHERE a2.ArtNrLong IS NOT NULL AND
      a1.ArtNrLong IS NULL AND
      a1.ArtNrShort = 'mik25';
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use an input parameter the ArtNrShort I want to check and update because I also have some different scenarios I need to check/update in a different way.

Comment: I have answered the question which you asked.  Maybe your question needs an update.

Comment: Soryy, I willl do that

Comment: Just add another condition to the `WHERE` clause limiting to only certain `ArtNrShort` values.

Comment: I did this: .......WHERE a2.ArtNrLong IS NOT NULL AND a1.ArtNrLong IS NULL AND a1.ArtNrShort = '%s' This still does not work. Is the way I pass the parameter not correct?

Comment: I pasted the 'mik25' value directly in my query as above. But after executing the query the ArtNrLong is not updated